# how to find the selected item in list view when we are using groups in listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have managed this in list view for grouping items in list view i have customer table  have columns with

```
                                      category id
                                     category name 




                       categories
                    -----------
                    category name 1
                    category name 2
                    category name 3

                    price ranges
                    -----------
                    ALL
                   0-500
                   500-1000
```

I have done above task but i have problem with checking selected item in groups in list view ..
[image]

my problem is how we fire the event like  if i select the first item in first group in list view i want to do something ....

and if i select the first item in second group in list view i want do something...

and some where i have to use the selected item  text in events.....

how i find the checking ...

can any one help on this .....

Many thanks....

and this is  my code

```
    private void categorieslist()
    {
        lstviewcategories.View = View.Details;
        lstviewcategories.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader() { Width = lstviewcategories.Width - 20 });
        lstviewcategories.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
        lstviewcategories.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
        lstviewcategories.Dock = DockStyle.None;

        ListViewGroup categorygroup = new ListViewGroup("Category Types",HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lstviewcategories.Groups.Add(categorygroup);


        var categorytypes = (from categories in abc.categories
                             select categories.category_Name).ToList();

        lstviewcategories.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = "ALL", Group = categorygroup });
        foreach (string item in categorytypes)
        {

            lstviewcategories.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = item.ToString(), Group = categorygroup });

        }

        ListViewGroup pricerangegroup = new ListViewGroup("Price Ranges", HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lstviewcategories.Groups.Add(pricerangegroup);

        lstviewcategories.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = "ALL", Group = pricerangegroup });
        lstviewcategories.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = "0-500", Group = pricerangegroup });
        lstviewcategories.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = "500-1000", Group = pricerangegroup });
        lstviewcategories.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = "1000+", Group = pricerangegroup });   
    }
```

**EDIT :**

```
        private void lstviewcategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // int index = 0;


        if (lstviewcategories.SelectedItems.Count > 0 &&lstviewcategories.SelectedItems[0].Group.Name == "Category Types")
        {
            string text = lstviewcategories.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString();

            var categorywithids = (from categorytypes in abc.categories
                                   where categorytypes.category_Name.Equals(text)
                                   select categorytypes.category_Id).SingleOrDefault();


            var productcategoty = from productswithcatgories in abc.product1
                                  where productswithcatgories.category_Id.Equals(categorywithids)
                                  select new
                                  {

                                      productid = productswithcatgories.product_Id, //0                                                                 
                                      productnam = productswithcatgories.product_Name, //1
                                      productimage = productswithcatgories.product_Image, //2
                                      productprice = productswithcatgories.product_Price,//3
                                      productdescr = productswithcatgories.product_Description,//4                                        
                                  };
            productbindingsource.DataSource = productcategoty;
            productgridview.DataSource = productbindingsource;
            productgridview.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            productgridview.Columns[4].Visible = false; 

        }
  }
```

Comment: would any one pls help on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get SelectedItems for example in `SelectedIndexChanged` event and check group like below:

```
private void lstviewcategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(lstviewcategories.SelectedItems.Count > 0 && lstviewcategories.SelectedItems[0].Group.Name == "group name")
       //do smth    
}
```

if MultiSelect property is enabled and for example you want to check selected items on some kind button click, loop through all selected items:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lstviewcategories.SelectedItems)
    {
       if(item.Group.Name == "group name")
           //do smth
    }
}
```

Comment: if i put this line  if(lstviewcategories.SelectedItems[0].Group.Name == "group name") i got the error like   InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

Comment: sorry I forgot to check if at least one item is selected. Edited answer. added `lstviewcategories.SelectedItems.Count > 0`

Comment: but its not working ...i have updated my code .....see my updated code it does not go to inside if loop...

Comment: @user899271 the problem is that the groups Name property has not been set (only the Header property). Change your check for this and it will work. However, checking magic strings like this is not really good practise and can cause a maintenance nightmare down the road.

Comment: @user899271, you can set it like so: `categorygroup.Name = "..";`

Comment: thanks.. but i have one string named  "All" how can i get this from selected listview

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a class derived from ListViewItem and add an enumeration property which you can query in the SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
public class CustomListViewItem : ListViewItem
{
    public CustomListViewItemType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum CustomListViewItemType
{
    Type1 = 0,
    Type2 = 1
}
```

---

```
lstviewcategories.Items.Add(new CustomListViewItem() { Text = "ALL", Group = pricerangegroup, Type = CustomListViewItemType.Type2 });
```

---

```
void lstviewcategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstviewcategories.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        CustomListViewItem customListItem = (CustomListViewItem)lstviewcategories.SelectedItems[0];
        switch (customListItem.Type)
        { 
            case CustomListViewItemType.Type1:
                {
                    //...
                }break;
            case CustomListViewItemType.Type2:
                {
                    //...
                }break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would name the enumeration constants as you require to match your groups.

Comment: so how can i use the item text in this case case CustomListViewItemType.Type1: 
                { 
                    //... 
                }break;

Comment: You can access the ListViewItems Text property like so `string text = customListItem.Text;`